# Bootstrap 4.1 Vertical Navs how to mr-auto/ml-auto badge

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is `navs` not `navbar`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical

[image]

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i>
            Link A
            <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill">140</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i>
            Link B
            <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill">300</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

tired change

`<span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill">`

to

`<span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill ml-auto">`

but didn't work

Edited: see @Temani Afif answer below

if with `d-flex` only

[image]

with `d-flex align-items-center` solved the problem

[image]

Comment: have you tried `mr-auto`?

Comment: yes ml-auto and mr-auto both not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `a` element a flex container to be able to use `ml-auto`/`mr-auto`. Simply add `d-flex` to `a`:

I also added `align-items-center` to center but it's not mandatory:

```css
.nav {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i>
            Link A
            <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill ml-auto">140</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i>
            Link B
            <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill ml-auto">300</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thankyou so much, must add `d-flex align-items-center` to get this work, if only d-flex, the badge look something wrong

Comment: @kenken9999 it look stretched not wrong ;) because the default alignment is stretch